# Не отправляется картинка в письме

Tags: php, email, file-get-contents

Я беру картинку с сервера по прямому пути вот так.

```
$path = 'http://mydomen.ru/myfolder/mycat.jpg';
$file = file_get_contents($path);
```

Потом я прикладываю эту картинку к письму

```
$body .= "--".$bound1."\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: image/".$ctype.";\r\n";
$body .= " name=\"$fl\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$body .= "Content-ID: <$fl>\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: inline;\r\n";

$body .= " filename=\"$fl\"\r\n\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file))."\n";
```

Все работает без ошибок, но в письме вместо картинки приходит содержимое.

```
9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAiYB4ADASIA AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3 ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1d
```

В чём ошибка?

Comment: ну вы же её сами и энкодите - `chunk_split(base64_encode($file))`

Comment: @n.osennij так же нужно делать чтобы вставить в тело письма?